# Restructure / rebuild json data tree

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
  "company": [
    { "region": [ "Europe", "Germany" ], "productLine": "Produce" },
    { "region": [ "Europe", "France" ], "productLine": "Produce" }
    ],
    "company2": [
    { "region": [ "Europe", "Germany" ], "productLine": "Produce" },
    {  "region": [ "Americas", "USA" ], "productLine": "Produce" }
    ]
}
```

With this json data how can I rebuild it so that I have Europe/Americas value as the primary(unique) node with Germany/France as it's children? company/company1 would be sub-children of France/Germany. I cant seem to figure out how to build arrays while keeping the relations correct. I essence I need to reverse the node tree.

Expected Output:

Tree structure like this:

```
-Europe
   -France
      -Company
      -Company2
```

I also need a special structure for a tree plugin:

```
var source = [ { label: "Europe", items: [
   {label: "France", items: [
      {label: "SuperShop", items: [
            {label: "Produce"}
         ]}
      ]
   }]
}]
```

What I need in the end is an Object array with value pair: label, items. Items being an object with sub-objects within.

Comment: Add the intended output for the given data.

Comment: Does the expected output need to be a json object, or can it be an array/hash?

Comment: It can be array, as long as it's well structured.

Comment: Are you using a framework(like jquery)?

Comment: Yes, I am using jQuery.

Comment: Your original input is invalid. You have objects with duplicate keys (the "region" key).

Comment: @Paulpro: and the first company array doesn't have a closing bracket

Comment: Corrected the json sample.

Comment: @DominicM Can you provide the desired output for the input you created?  I do not see the direct connection between the two.

Comment: See edit. Objects/arrays/nodes should merge so that they are unique in their own branches.

Comment: Please be careful that when editing the question you don't make a change that invalidates existing answers. It might be more sensible to ask a new question following on from this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, I don't know why you need the new format, but it seems overly complex. If you have a large data set that you are looking through, you are going to take a hit on speed because, under it's current set up, you are going to have traverse over every element of the new array to find the one you are looking for ...

```
var inputs = {
  "company": [
    { "region": [ "Europe", "Germany" ], "productLine": "Produce" },
    { "region": [ "Europe", "France" ], "productLine": "Produce" }
    ],
    "company2": [
    { "region": [ "Europe", "Germany" ], "productLine": "Produce" },
    {  "region": [ "Americas", "USA" ], "productLine": "Produce" }
    ]
};

var converter = {};

// This new format requires a 2 step process to prevent it from being N^2
// So convert the input into a tree
//   Region
//     -> Country
//       -> Company
//         -> Array of Products
for(var company in inputs){
  for(var i = 0; i < inputs[company].length; i++){
    // Because the regions are an array of hashes it is simplest
    // to grab the value by using the previously gathered keys
    // and the key region
    var r = inputs[company][i]['region'];

    // Check if the region exists.  If not create it.
    if(!converter[r[0]]){
      converter[r[0]] = {};
    }
    // Check if the country exists.  If not create it.
    if(!converter[r[0]][r[1]]){
      converter[r[0]][r[1]] = {};
    }
    // Add the company to the array.
    if(!converter[r[0]][r[1]][company]){
      converter[r[0]][r[1]][company] = [];
    }
    converter[r[0]][r[1]][company].push(inputs[company][i]['productLine']);
  }
}

var outputs = [];

// Now walk converter and generate the desired object.
for( var region in converter){
  converted_region = {};
  converted_region["label"] = region;
  converted_region["items"] = [];
  for( var country in converter[region]){
    converted_country = {};
    converted_country["label"] = country;
    converted_country["items"] = [];
    for( var company in converter[region][country]){
      converted_company = {};
      converted_company["label"] = company;
      converted_company["items"] = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < converter[region][country][company].length; i++){
        converted_company["items"].push(converter[region][country][company][i]);
      }
      converted_country["items"].push(converted_company);
    }
    converted_region["items"].push(converted_country);
  }
  outputs.push(converted_region);
}
```

Comment: What does "['region']" mean?  I will not have region values to hand as they are dynamic.

Comment: Don't forget `var`! And don't use for-in-loops with arrays!

Comment: @DominicM given the input you describe, to get to the [region,country] value, you have to use inputs[company][index_of_array]["region"]

Comment: Have you tested it? because there are too many mistakes. What sign is supposed to be after "i" in line 2?

Comment: @DominicM fixed.  it needed a <.

Comment: It looks like I actually need a slight change, how would I change this to: { label: "Europe", items: [
                    { label: "France" },
                    { label: "Germany" }
                ]
                }, ... with other nodes with label and theyr values in items?

Comment: @DominicM can you update your question to show the necessary formats?

Comment: Updated! Thanks for helping me out, can't for the life of me figure it out on my own :)